# How can I set a default value for Angular Material Slide Toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

How can I set a default value for the **slide toggle**?

I can set an initial value for my property in ngOnInit, but there must be an 'Angular Way'

```html
            <mat-slide-toggle
              [checked]="system.ignoreUser"
              (toggleChange)="system.ignoreUser= !system.ignoreUser">
              <span *ngIf="system.ignoreUser">{{'ignoreUser' | translate}}</span>
              <span *ngIf="!system.ignoreUser">{{'ignoreUser' | translate}}</span>
            </mat-slide-toggle>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) you can set default value like below:

```
mySlideToggle= new FormControl(true,[Validators.required]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `checked` input property:

```html
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="true"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `ngModel` in your html:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="system.ignoreUser">
    <span *ngIf="system.ignoreUser">{{'ignoreUser' | translate}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="!system.ignoreUser">{{'ignoreUser' | translate}}</span>
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Comment: np @HugoSeleiro

Answer (score 2):

`[(ngModel)]` worked for me in reactiveForm angular 13:

```
<mat-slide-toggle 
   formControlName="super" 
   labelPosition="before" 
   color="primary"
   (change)="slideToggleChange($event)"
   [(ngModel)]="checked">
</mat-slide-toggle>
```